# Unable to start cordapp-example from IntelliJ

Tags: corda

I'm trying to run sample cordapp-example code by cloning from [Github repository](https://github.com/corda/samples) using:

```
git clone https://github.com/corda/samples
```

I followed all the steps as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html#downloading-the-example-cordapp) for running the application from IntelliJ.

```html
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe" -ea -javaagent:lib/quasar.jar "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=58722:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Utkarsh\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath1292589534.jar com.example.test.NodeDriverKt
[INFO] 13:01:05,307 [driver-pool-thread-0] network.NodeInfoFilesCopier. - Now watching: C:\Users\Utkarsh\Desktop\corda-sandbox\samples\cordapp-example\build\node-driver\20200103-073059.357\NotaryService
[WARN] 13:01:05,640 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Unable to locate JAR for class given by `org.jboss.byteman.agent.Transformer` on classpath: org.jboss.byteman.agent.Transformer [errorCode=6tcm1g, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.3/6tcm1g]
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.byteman.agent.Transformer
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl.resolveJar(DriverDSLImpl.kt:149) ~[corda-node-driver-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl.access$resolveJar(DriverDSLImpl.kt:80) ~[corda-node-driver-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$bytemanJarPath$2.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:131) ~[corda-node-driver-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$bytemanJarPath$2.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:80) ~[corda-node-driver-4.3.jar:?]
 at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.2.71.jar:1.2.71-release-64 (1.2.71)]
 at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl.getBytemanJarPath(DriverDSLImpl.kt) ~[corda-node-driver-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl.startNodeInternal(DriverDSLImpl.kt:637) ~[corda-node-driver-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl.startRegisteredNode(DriverDSLImpl.kt:257) ~[corda-node-driver-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl.startRegisteredNode$default(DriverDSLImpl.kt:218) ~[corda-node-driver-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl.startSingleNotary(DriverDSLImpl.kt:505) ~[corda-node-driver-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl.startNotaries(DriverDSLImpl.kt:493) ~[corda-node-driver-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl.access$startNotaries(DriverDSLImpl.kt:80) ~[corda-node-driver-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$start$3.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:373) ~[corda-node-driver-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$start$3.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:80) ~[corda-node-driver-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$map$$inlined$also$lambda$1$1.invoke(CordaFutureImpl.kt:36) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.ValueOrException$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:130) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.OpenFuture$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:142) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$map$$inlined$also$lambda$1.invoke(CordaFutureImpl.kt:36) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$map$$inlined$also$lambda$1.invoke(CordaFutureImpl.kt) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.concurrent.ConcurrencyUtils.match(ConcurrencyUtils.kt:19) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$thenMatch$1.invoke(CordaFutureImpl.kt:25) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$thenMatch$1.invoke(CordaFutureImpl.kt) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl$thenImpl$1.accept(CordaFutureImpl.kt:155) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl$thenImpl$1.accept(CordaFutureImpl.kt:142) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.set(CordaFutureImpl.kt:148) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.ValueOrException$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:129) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.OpenFuture$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:142) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$map$$inlined$also$lambda$1.invoke(CordaFutureImpl.kt:36) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$map$$inlined$also$lambda$1.invoke(CordaFutureImpl.kt) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.concurrent.ConcurrencyUtils.match(ConcurrencyUtils.kt:19) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$thenMatch$1.invoke(CordaFutureImpl.kt:25) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$thenMatch$1.invoke(CordaFutureImpl.kt) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl$thenImpl$1.accept(CordaFutureImpl.kt:155) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl$thenImpl$1.accept(CordaFutureImpl.kt:142) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.set(CordaFutureImpl.kt:148) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.ValueOrException$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:129) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.OpenFuture$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:142) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$fork$$inlined$also$lambda$1.run(CordaFutureImpl.kt:22) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_231]
[INFO] 13:01:05,640 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Starting out-of-process Node Notary Service, debug port is not enabled, byteMan: not in classpath
[INFO] 13:01:05,774 [Log4j2-TF-1-AsyncLogger[AsyncContextNoThreadLocal@18b4aac2]-1] manifests.Manifests. - 141 attributes loaded from 224 stream(s) in 109ms, 141 saved, 3371 ignored: ["ActiveMQ-Version", "Agent-Class", "Ant-Version", "Application-Class", "Application-ID", "Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase", "Application-Name", "Application-Version", "Archiver-Version", "Automatic-Module-Name", "Bnd-LastModified", "Branch", "Build-Date", "Build-Host", "Build-Id", "Build-Java-Version", "Build-Jdk", "Build-Jdk-Spec", "Build-Job", "Build-Number", "Build-Revision", "Build-Time", "Build-Timestamp", "Build-Version", "Built-By", "Built-OS", "Built-Status", "Bundle-ActivationPolicy", "Bundle-Activator", "Bundle-Category", "Bundle-ClassPath", "Bundle-Classpath", "Bundle-Copyright", "Bundle-Description", "Bundle-DocURL", "Bundle-License", "Bundle-ManifestVersion", "Bundle-Name", "Bundle-NativeCode", "Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment", "Bundle-SymbolicName", "Bundle-Vendor", "Bundle-Version", "Caller-Allowable-Codebase", "Can-Redefine-Classes", "Can-Retransform-Classes", "Can-Set-Native-Method-Prefix", "Caplets", "Change", "Class-Path", "Codebase", "Corda-Platform-Version", "Corda-Release-Version", "Corda-Revision", "Corda-Vendor", "Cordapp-Contract-Licence", "Cordapp-Contract-Name", "Cordapp-Contract-Vendor", "Cordapp-Contract-Version", "Cordapp-Workflow-Licence", "Cordapp-Workflow-Name", "Cordapp-Workflow-Vendor", "Cordapp-Workflow-Version", "Created-By", "DynamicImport-Package", "Eclipse-BuddyPolicy", "Eclipse-LazyStart", "Embed-Dependency", "Export-Package", "Extension-Name", "Fragment-Host", "Git-Revision", "Git-Url", "Gradle-Version", "Hibernate-JpaVersion", "Hibernate-VersionFamily", "Ignore-Package", "Implementation-Build", "Implementation-Build-Date", "Implementation-Build-Id", "Implementation-Title", "Implementation-URL", "Implementation-Url", "Implementation-Vendor", "Implementation-Vendor-Id", "Implementation-Version", "Import-Package", "Include-Resource", "JCabi-Build", "JCabi-Date", "JCabi-Version", "JVM-Args", "Java-Agents", "Java-Vendor", "Java-Version", "Kotlin-Runtime-Component", "Kotlin-Version", "Liquibase-Package", "Log4jReleaseKey", "Log4jReleaseManager", "Log4jReleaseVersion", "Main-Class", "Main-class", "Major-Version", "Manifest-Version", "Min-Java-Version", "Min-Platform-Version", "Min-Update-Version", "Module-Email", "Module-Origin", "Module-Owner", "Module-Source", "Multi-Release", "Originally-Created-By", "Os-Arch", "Os-Name", "Os-Version", "Permissions", "Premain-Class", "Private-Package", "Provide-Capability", "Require-Capability", "SCM-Revision", "SCM-url", "Scm-Connection", "Scm-Revision", "Scm-Url", "Sealed", "Service-Component", "Specification-Title", "Specification-Vendor", "Specification-Version", "System-Properties", "Target-Platform-Version", "Tool", "Trusted-Library", "URL", "X-Compile-Source-JDK", "X-Compile-Target-JDK", "service", "url"]
[INFO] 13:01:19,312 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.RPCClient. - Startup took 1762 msec
[INFO] 13:01:19,439 [driver-pool-thread-1] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Node handle is ready. NodeInfo: NodeInfo(addresses=[localhost:10016], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=Notary Service, L=Zurich, C=CH], platformVersion=5, serial=1578036675653), WebAddress: localhost:10019
[INFO] 13:01:19,472 [main] network.NodeInfoFilesCopier. - Now watching: C:\Users\Utkarsh\Desktop\corda-sandbox\samples\cordapp-example\build\node-driver\20200103-073059.357\PartyA
[INFO] 13:01:19,474 [main] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Starting out-of-process Node PartyA, debug port is not enabled, byteMan: not in classpath
[INFO] 13:01:19,495 [main] network.NodeInfoFilesCopier. - Now watching: C:\Users\Utkarsh\Desktop\corda-sandbox\samples\cordapp-example\build\node-driver\20200103-073059.357\PartyB
[INFO] 13:01:19,497 [main] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Starting out-of-process Node PartyB, debug port is not enabled, byteMan: not in classpath
[INFO] 13:01:19,520 [main] network.NodeInfoFilesCopier. - Now watching: C:\Users\Utkarsh\Desktop\corda-sandbox\samples\cordapp-example\build\node-driver\20200103-073059.357\PartyC
[INFO] 13:01:19,524 [main] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Starting out-of-process Node PartyC, debug port is not enabled, byteMan: not in classpath
[INFO] 13:01:43,753 [driver-pool-thread-1] internal.RPCClient. - Startup took 2298 msec
[INFO] 13:01:44,301 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.RPCClient. - Startup took 2610 msec
[INFO] 13:01:44,510 [driver-pool-thread-1] internal.RPCClient. - Startup took 756 msec
[INFO] 13:01:44,598 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Node handle is ready. NodeInfo: NodeInfo(addresses=[localhost:10024], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=PartyB, L=New York, C=US], platformVersion=5, serial=1578036698710), WebAddress: localhost:10027
[INFO] 13:01:44,620 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Node handle is ready. NodeInfo: NodeInfo(addresses=[localhost:10028], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=PartyC, L=Paris, C=FR], platformVersion=5, serial=1578036698576), WebAddress: localhost:10031
[INFO] 13:01:44,642 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Node handle is ready. NodeInfo: NodeInfo(addresses=[localhost:10020], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB], platformVersion=5, serial=1578036699110), WebAddress: localhost:10023
```

I can see that the nodes are up and running, but what is that error related to?

Moreover, I've also started the Spring application using `gradlew.bat runPartyXServer` but still unable to create IOUs (e.g. from localhost:50005 - PartyA; not able to view other parties in dropdown ) like I was able to create when I ran everything from the console instead of IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is just a warning output by the driver tests when byteman (a java agent) is not used. You can ignore it.

`runPartyXServer` is likely just starting the spring web app, not running the node itself.

Try running the `nodes/runnodes.sh` script or `java -jar corda.jar` in the directory of each generated node.